# How to update entity attribute without loading JPA entity

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How to update entity attribute without loading JPA entity
We are trying to update status attribute after loading entity

```
public User updateUserStatus(Long id, UserStatus status) {
    User user = findById(id);
    user.setStatus(status);
    user = save(user);

    return user;
}
```

Comment: it's not clear what is your question

Comment: What do you want to return from your method if you don't want to load the entity?

Comment: This needs a lot more detail. You could be asking about performance optimizations, not needing or wanting to load full relationships on User just to have a fk changed, but even that has any number of possible solutions based on details you haven't specified at all. Maybe start with what about the current code behavior it is you don't like, and break into the mappings and SQL involved if required.

Comment: I want to update the status without loading user, I don't need to return the Entity as well. I want the call to return faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a direct update. Note that this leaves the first level cache in an inconsistent state and does not trigger any JPA life cycle events.

With Spring Data JPA you would create a method like the following in your repository:

```java
@Modifying
@Query("update User u set u.status = :status where u.id = :id")
void updateStatus(Long id, UserStatus status);
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries for more details